# extract all email addresses from all csv files in working directory using Linux

Tags: linux, csv, sed, grep

I am trying to grep all of the email addresses from all csv files in a working directory and print them to \n delimiter text file. I tried:

```
egrep -o '.*@.*' *.csv > alltheemails.txt
```

But, this seems to capture the entire line.

Then, I tried:

```
egrep -o ',.*@.*,' csv/*.csv > alltheemails.txt
```

I was attempting to only copy the email address and maybe the , delimiter, which can change later. This also copied the entire line.

Then, I tried:

```
egrep -o ',.*@.*,' csv/*.csv | sed -e 's/^,...@//g' | tee alltheemails.txt
```

This still captured everything in front of the email. I tried:

```
egrep -o ',.*@.*,' csv/*.csv | sed -e 's/*^,.*@//g' | tee alltheemails.txt
```

And many other variations, including:

```
sed -e 's/.*^[[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.\_\-\+\*@[[a-zA-Z0-9]-\.]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}$]/.*^[[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.\_\-\+\*@[[a-zA-Z0-9]-\.]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}$/g' csv/*.csv | egrep -eo | tee alltheemails.txt
```

This produced:

`firstname,surname,lead,ip,address,city,state,postal,phone,date,range,daytime,interest,sex,dob,worktime,profit_estim,extra2`

Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: What is the format of the csv file?

Comment: Some have only , delimiters and some have " and , delimiters.

Comment: I am doing 'cat *.csv | tee newfile.csv' and am looking at them. They are all separated by , only. When this is done, I have an idea to use tr '.' '\n' | egrep -e '@' | tee newfile.txt. Does that make any sense to you?

Comment: What about `grep -E -o '[^@", ]+@[0-9a-z.]+[a-z][a-z]' csv/*.csv` ?  You know your delimiters on the left-hand side, and you know what characters are permitted on the right-hand side.  Yes, this regex could be refined, but it's good enough to show you a different way of approaching this.

Comment: Oh, and yes, splitting the file on commas then grepping for @ may indeed get you all the email addresses, and possibly other stuff too depending on your file (which we haven't seen).  Note that `egrep` is deprecated in Linux, if you need ERE, you should use `grep -E` instead.  And for a pattern as simple as `@`, you don't really need the `-e` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl solution for all .csv files in the current directory
The email address can be in any field

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /([^,@"]+@[^,@"]+)/' *.csv > alltheemails.txt
```

Prints the match `$1`
From the regular expression `/([^,@"]+@[^,@"]+)/`
`[^,@"]+` = one or more occurrences of any character except ,@"

input:

```
name,surname"user1@dom.com,address
name,surname,nomail,address2
nam,test,user2@dom.com"new york, central park
al,ternative,name11@mail.com,paris
alternative,name11@mail.com,paris
```

output:

```
user1@dom.com
user2@dom.com
name11@mail.com
name11@mail.com
```

---

If you prefer awk:

`awk '{if (match($0, /[^,@"]+@[^,@"]+/, m)) print m[0]}' *.csv > alltheemails.txt`

Comment: For a more robust email address regular expression, see:  http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Answer (score 1):

With `grep -o` you need to provide a regex which matches only the text you actually want to extract.

```
grep -Eo '[^,"@]*@[^,"@]*' csv/*.csv
```

(The `-E` option isn't really useful here; but it's harmless. If you want to use some ERE features in your regex, then it will matter.)

Comment: Theoretically, the email address RFC allows addresses which contain double quotes, etc; but in this day and age, when junior PHP programmers create web forms which will barely tolerate an address with a period or an underscore, if you're lucky, such addresses are basically extinct.

Comment: +1 on the annoyance that people can't seem to read RFCs. But on the RHS of this address, you know what characters are permitted in hostnames in DNS. Might as well narrow things down, no?  `@([a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]+\.)+([a-z]{2,}|xn--[a-z0-9]+$` ?

Comment: @ghoti Internal dashes are allowed elsewhere, too.

Comment: Righto, just not at the beginning of a name. Fixed.

Comment: And IDNA labels should be allowed everywhere, not just in the TLD.

Comment: Sigh. True. Okay, this is becoming more work than a comment is worth.  You win.  Upvote for you. :)

Comment: Though waitasec. IDN labels are matched by `[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]+` are they not? Where would my RE above fail to match the domain part of an email address?

Comment: @ghoti Yes ... I meant to comment on that, too, before you gave up. (-: Your internal dashes policy is now too lenient. You can have internal dashes, but not two consecutive ones, except in IDNA. You are now also permitting final dashes, which are disallowed.

Comment: Hmm, and even that may be tricky, as a *hostname* may have multiple dashes, even if a domain name does not. And then you get into region-specific limitations, like `example.on.ca`, and a RE can't be expected to know which two-letter 3rd-level domains under `.ca` represent provinces, and which are actual registered domains.  Yep, email address validation isn't easy.

Comment: And the intent of IDNA is to allow all of Unicode in labels, so somebody could have `lemmy@motörhead.example` and not specify it in IDNA form.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from these csv:

```
~$ more *.csv 
::::::::::::::
email2.csv
::::::::::::::
mail@new.com,address,surname
test,noreply@com.com,new york, central park
ternative,aaaaaaaaa@b.com,paris
name,surname,nomail,address2
::::::::::::::
email.csv
::::::::::::::
user1@dom.com,address,name,surname
name,surname,nomail,address2
test,user2@dom.com,new york, central park
al,ternative,name11@mail.com,paris
```

EDIT:A python solution (the code is wrapped with the `-c` option, see `man python` within bash about this):

```
python -c '
import sys

# needed to handle the bash argument, eg. the csv name
# skip first argument, it's the option "-c" itself
csvfile = str(sys.argv[1:][0])  
email_list = []

with open(csvfile) as f:
    for X in f:
        # field delimiter
        s = X.split(",")    
        for Z in s:
            # find the email address using "@"
            if "@" in Z:    
                email_list.append(Z)
for I in email_list:
    print I
' <(cat *.csv) > alltheemails.txt
```

You should use this python code from bash this way: `python -c 'code between single quotes' <(cat *.csv) > alltheemails.txt`. The bash command `<(cat *.csv)` combines the `cat *.csv` output with a redirection to create the python process input.

Of course you can remove the comments using the code. If you prefer, you can also put this code in a script to execute this way: `python grep.py <(cat *.csv)`.
Output:

```
mail@new.com
noreply@com.com
aaaaaaaaa@b.com
user1@dom.com
user2@dom.com
name11@mail.com
```

Comment: That's the problem. Not all of the csv files have the email address in the same columns.

Comment: This was not clear at the beginning... In this case I think you need to use a loop to iterate over every row. Could be done better in another language, like `python`. You can execute python script?

Comment: I can. I will update python and try out your suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '/@/!d' -e 's/.*/,&,/;s/[[:space:]]//g;s/,[^@,]*,/,/g;s/,\(.*\),/\1/' csv/*csv
```

will extract all email (if present) per line of csv file. result is email ofthe line separated by the `,`

if 1 by line, add `;s/,/\n/g` (for GNU sed, and a real new line instead of `n` for posix version)